universal contemporary Chord symbols
Please advise on universally understood contemporary symbols for Minor Sixth chords having the sixth in the bass eg "F minor sixth" written "D F Ab C" as a chord-chart symbol, there have I think been changes/improvements since I learned 1950s...regards JXC

There might not have been any changes in the last 70 years. How would you think to write this chord? Also I'm afraid you'll find that there's nothing "universal" about chord symbols these days. You'll want to be aware of the musicians and genres who will read your charts and do your best to match that culture and notation style.

 As I feared. The Gypsies I used to play with on the Continent has no concept of C,D,E but called/wrote D(oh) R(é) M(i). ...took me a moment to differentiate D from D, and a Half-diminished will be the same... Thanks

Another thing that's changed is it's consider most polite these days to call them "Roma" and to not use the g word anymore. When referring to the scale or genre, it's more divided. I've never heard anyone say "Roma jazz" or "the Roma scale" but some people do avoid using the g word in those cases also. Fixed do note names are very common in European languages outside of English and German.

@Todd Wilcox - Django was a Gypsy, we all agree on that. Roma jazz? seems like PC gone mad! We're straying too close to Monica territory for my liking!!

@Tim I’m just reporting facts as I know them. The g-word is considered offensive by many. I think everyone involved in music would be helped by knowing that, so they can make an informed choice about when and whether they use that word in the future. Certainly professionals often want to choose their words very carefully since interpersonal skills are highly valued in creative fields.

@Tim Are you sure it'd be Roma jazz and not, say, Sinti jazz? Important distinction if you ascribe it to only one group.

@Divizna - or even Manouche..?

I should perhaps have said Tzigane, as my cohort were mainly from Russia; Tho' the Parisians, describing themselves as Manouche, spoke Sinti. My maternal grandfather described himself as a gypsy and, never used the word Roma. Djelem djelem, lungomé Dromeya... Mala dilem koraré Romesa... My heart cares not for names if spoken with love

@ToddWilcox The facts as I know them are: 1. Those I have met (and talked about it with, which admittedly wasn't that many) called themselves "Cikán" (which translates as "Gypsy"), rather than "Rom". The vocal protests I've seen mostly from gadžo white knights (pun unintended but apt). But I concede that there isn't agreement among the people themselves. 2. Roma are only one of several groups (can I say "tribes"?) of Gypsies, which is also why the Sinti alliance protested against using "Roma" as an umbrella term. So I feel very uneasy about being asked to call all Gypsies "Roma".

To me, it feels as if Russian leaders decided that "Slav" is offensive (it originated as our own word, but it did then, after all, become the etymological root for "slave") and insisted on calling all Slavs "Russians" (well, they are kinda doing it to Ukrainians already). Call me a Slav any day. Don't try to call me a Russian. I'm Czech.

@Divizna Could be this is more of a thing in English because in English we have a word that means roughly “to scam, rip off, or steal” which comes from the g-word so maybe people in primarily English speaking countries are more likely to find the association problematic? It’s definitely not just me. If you just google it you’ll find lots of other sources.

@Divizna This article is written by a member of the community in question and clarifies that it’s not so simple, at the same time it doesn’t seem wise to assume that no one will be offended by using the g word: https://medium.com/ayzoh-magazine/gypsy-what-is-in-a-word-pride-or-prejudice-e5a7d869428d  It also seems like “Romani” might be more widely acceptable than “Roma”.

@ToddWilcox - seems like the word to which you refer - gyp - has only an American English connotation. Gyp as used in Br. English is used for a pain or discomfort - 'I have a gyppy tummy'. (Emanating from Egyptian).  In 70 odd years I've never ever heard it used in a derogatory manner in UK.

The chord Dm7♭5 is also commonly written D∅7 (circle with slash): “D half-diminished seventh”.

I'd hardly call that notation "universally understood", though.

@Divizna Good point. From what I know, there is no universal chord notation.

Does a half diminished chord sign even need the 7? I've used it for years just as 'circle and slash', as the 7 part is obvious.

@Tim I've never seen it without, but you're right that it's redundant.

Fm6/D is the first to come to mind.
However, with those notes, and D underneath, it could also be called Dm7♭5.
The basic triad constitutes a diminished triad - D F A♭. Had the other note been C♭, it would be a full diminished chord. However, it's not quite. Thus, another name could be half-diminished, as in Dø, but that would tend to not be represented by a chord whose name started with F.

Thank you Tim; Dm7b5 is how I am used to writing it, but jazz cohort leave all manner of shorthand scribbles on their parts and as one writes the accidental before the A on the stave and yet calls it "A flat" with the modifier AFTER the note I wondered if there were any modern symbols which disambiguate. Possibly not. Russian and Manouche musicians i've worked with use the inversion in question automatically, UK and USA guitarists do not.Regards

I feel like I've seen slash chords written with the bass considered separate from the chord name. In other words, another way I've seen a chord like this written is simply Fm/D. Even though D is not part of an Fm chord, the primary symbol is not updated to accommodate the bass note in all cases. This might be a rock guitar thing, so jazz players may object strongly. One thing leaving out the "6" does is clarify what notes upper structure players should (or should not) highlight.

Thank you @Todd; the slash implies, then, that the folloing note is in the bass? It's economical if so. Regards

@JXCoudrille Oh yeah, I thought they had slashes in the 50s. The letter after the slash indicates the lowest sounding note. What might be called a "C 6-4 chord" (AKA "second inversion") in the classical world would just be written "C/G" for jazz, rock, pop, musical theatre, etc. Normally the note after the slash is part of the chord (as in C/G), but I've seen lots of slash chords, especially in progressions, where the bass note would not normally be part of the chord symbol itself. Like "C - C/Bb - C/Ab - C/G". Basically a C major chord maintained over a descending bass line.

Thank you. I lack musical education beyond rudimentary schooling but my mentor was saxophonist Denis Ray who worked as a copyist for Campbell Connelly and wrote arrangements for the Ted Heath swing orchestra. I picked up much by osmosis, and I was a musical director with Southern Television on this shaky foundation. Out of the written business for decades, one forgets...

There's a tradition, particularly in song copies from the mid-20th century, of writing 'Fm6' even when the chord's clearly rooted on D and acts as a dominant of (say) Gm7.   Maybe because they were seen as 'ukulele shapes' rather than descriptors of harmonic function.   (Rather strangely, the same tradition sometimes describes a final, tonic 'C6' as 'Am7'.)
Modern players are deemed capable of dealing with the more functionally descriptive 'Dm7♭5'. Though 'Fm6' hasn't completely died out.
At least 'Fm6' and 'Dm7♭5' both describe the same 4 notes.  Don't get me started on what 'C11' thinks it means!   (Hint, it's almost NEVER the textbook 'pile of 3rds' C, E, G, B♭, D, F.)

 thank you!
